# How can i find each professional count and age count of a particular country( for eg US) in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

[image]

this is the example. from this i want to find each professional count and each age group count.

[image]

```
filter_data = FILTER customer by loc=='us';          
grunt> grp_data1 = GROUP filter_data by age;                                   
grunt> cnt_data = FOREACH grp_data1 generate group,COUNT(customer);
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use Hive or Spark for this? Pig has not been well maintained as a project for years

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a `GROUP BY` statement using `filter_data`. So, the same variable name has to be used inside `COUNT` function.

```
grunt> grp_data1 = GROUP filter_data by age;                                   
grunt> cnt_data = FOREACH grp_data1 generate group, COUNT(filter_data);
```